# Spring Intergration JPA. Обновление сущности в БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jpa, spring-integration

Есть проект на SpringIntegration. На jpa:outbound-channel-adapter поступают jpa сущности, которые должны персиститься в БД, если не существует записи с таким Id. Если Id существует, то обновить поля в БД, которые в сущности не пустые (не null).
В текущей реализации при обновлении поля, сущности которые равны null заменяют нулами данные в БД. Как их правильно соеденить? Возможно ли это сделать из коробки, средствами Spring Integration JPA, не создавая свой service-activator?

```
<int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter
            channel="VCardPersistChannel" 
            persist-mode="MERGE"
            entity-class="entities.blocks.jpa.SendRequestEntity"
            entity-manager-factory="externalEntityManagerfactory">
            <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="txManager" />
</int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Сущность:

```
@Entity(name = "SendRequestEntity")
@Table(name = "ITX_PT_SEND_REQUEST")
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(value=true)
public class SendRequestEntity {

    @Column
    @Id
    private String requestId;   

    @Column
    private String userId;

    @Column
    private String bindingId;

    @Column
    private String clientBlockId;

    @Column
    private String blockId;

    @Column
    private String blockType;

    @Column
    private Integer reasonId;

    @Column(name = "DATE_SEND")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateSend;

    @Column
    private String ewExtErrorCode;

    @Column
    private String callbackRequestId;

    @Column
    private String callbackBlockId;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date occurredOn;

    @Column(name = "DATE_CALLBACK")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCallback;

    @Column
    private String errorCode;

    @Column
    private String errorDesc;

    @Column(name = "DATE_NOTIFICATION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateNotification;

    //Getter - setters      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась запиливанием собственного ServiceActivator

```
public class SendRequestMerger {    

private EntityManager entityManager;

    public SendRequestMerger(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @ServiceActivator
    public SendRequestEntity handleMessage(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Message message) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{

        SendRequestEntity updateSendRequest = (SendRequestEntity)message.getPayload();

        SendRequestEntity currentSendRequest = entityManager.find(SendRequestEntity.class, updateSendRequest.getRequestId());
        if (currentSendRequest == null) {
                System.out.println("currentSendRequest is null");
                return updateSendRequest;
            }

        Field[] fields = SendRequestEntity.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field: fields){
            field.setAccessible(true);  
            if (field.get(updateSendRequest) != null )  {                               
                field.set(currentSendRequest, field.get(updateSendRequest));            
            }
        }   
        return currentSendRequest;

    }   

    public void destroy(){
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<!--  Мержим сущность  --> 
    <integration:channel id="VCardPersistChannel" />
    <integration:service-activator 
        ref="sendRequestEnricher"
        input-channel="VCardPersistChannel"
        output-channel="VCardPersistMergedChannel"/>        
    <bean id="sendRequestEnricher" 
        class="handlers.SendRequestMerger"
        destroy-method="destroy">
        <constructor-arg ref="externalEntityManagerfactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!--  Персист в БД  --> 
    <integration:channel id="VCardPersistMergedChannel" />  
    <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="VCardPersistMergedChannel" 
        persist-mode="MERGE"
        entity-class="entities.blocks.jpa.SendRequestEntity"
        entity-manager-factory="externalEntityManagerfactory">
        <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="txManager" />
    </int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```